# Delphi: Bind a Chart with a DBGrid

Tags: delphi, data-binding, teechart, dbgrid

I want to bind a Chart with a DBGrid.
Refer to the exhibit.
When I click in the DBGrid on number 3 (X-Axis), then the bar at position three should be highlighted(or a pointer to bar 3).
When I click on number 4 in the Grid then bar 4 is highlighted etc.
I'm using a TDBChart

Is there a way to do this?

[image: sample graph image]

Comment: You don't bind anything to the DBGrid. You bind it to the dataset to which the DBGrid is connected. A DBGrid is nothing but a display of data.

Comment: If you want the grid not to display the `Value` column, set its `Visible` property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what the charting component is, cannot provide a working example, but the key which you are looking for is to use the AfterScroll event for the dataset in the grid. Since each row represents a different record, that event is fired when the grid selection moves to the row.

Edit: This doesn't highlight with a box, but does change the color of the value marks at the top of each bar.  Hopefully this gets you on your way. MyQuery is what is feeding the datasource

```
var 
  savecolor : tcolor;

procedure MyForm.FormShow(Sender:TObject);
begin
 ...
 SaveColor := dbchart1.series[0].marks.items[0].color;
 ...
end;

procedure MyForm.MyQueryBeforeScroll(DataSet : TDataSet);
begin
  dbchart1.series[0].marks.items[MyQuery.recno-1].color := SaveColor;
end;

procedure MyForm.MyQueryAfterScroll(DataSet:TDataSet);
begin
 dbchart1.series[0].marks.items[MyQuery.recno-1].color := clRed;
end;
```

Comment: I'm using a TDBChart.

Comment: @coder007: Then that information should be in your question, so you don't waste people's time.